# Get data between last three years,

Tags: android, datetime, datetime-generation

I'm try to load data between lasst three years. i want to get data between current datetime and last 3 years back.

eg:-FROM 1/19/2009 TO current time (1/19/2012)

I get the current time as below.

```
String date= DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
```

Could someone please tell me the way to do this? If you have any worked through examples, that would be a real help!

Comment: if you want data from database then execute query for it and other then tell me.

Comment: are you facing problem with formatting or db query.. Pl. specify

Comment: Thankz Newts.I want to take the current and last dates and after set to textviews.

Comment: thankz vinay. how can i load backdate(3 years ago) to text view? minus from current date? if yes how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Calender's `add()`

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Log.d("current date",dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -3);
        Log.d("3 years previous date",dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
01-19 05:34:52.148: DEBUG/current date(556): 19/01/2012
01-19 05:34:52.148: DEBUG/3 years previous date(556): 19/01/2009
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the question? How to get date 3 years earlier? Then this code will be useful:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    //set up time to the last minute of today
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

    long to = c.getTimeInMillis();// end point of period

    c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1 * yearCount);

    long since = c.getTimeInMillis();//start point of period
```